# for loop with Array2D<Type>(columns: NumColumns, rows: NumRows)

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, generator

I'm using a Array2D. I like to use it also when performing an action on all elements.

```
for e in arr
```

does not work because Generator is not available. I searched for other solutions, but all where focusing on stanrdard arrays (using flatMap or reduce).
Any idea to do it easy and short? Of course I can write two loops. But that's not cool. :-)

EDIT:
My fault. Array2D is defined elsewhere and not a Swift library structure (as I thought), so I can change everything by myself. Sorry.

Comment: How is `Array2D` defined?

Comment: That was the perfect hint! :-)

Comment: Your link was to Swift 2.0. I'm still using XCode 6.4. But thanks nevertheless.